# Unrecognized name: BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table including order_date, member_id, channel (including phone, email, msg and In-person), and reached_ind (0 if we could not reach out to the customer and 1 if it was successful)
Bellow is part of the code I wrote, but I can't figure out why the reached_ind column name is not recognized.

```
SELECT 
  month_of_the_order,
  channel,          
CASE
  WHEN (reached_ind =1 AND channel = 'email') THEN SUM(members.distinct_num_calls) OVER(
    PARTITION BY month_of_the_order
    ORDER BY month_of_the_order
  ) END as email_success_count       
FROM
  (SELECT 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date) AS month_of_the_order,
    COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS distinct_num_calls,
    channel
  FROM
    `quiz-one-382819.coding_project.cvs`             
   GROUP BY 
    month_of_the_order, 
    channel       
  ) members
```

Comment: @nbk It works in BigQuery console and is [documented](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause): *GROUP BY clauses may also refer to aliases. If a query contains aliases in the SELECT clause, those aliases override names in the corresponding FROM clause.* While I prefer positional grouping (which is more verbose) if it's supported by the DBMS

Comment: Your subquery doesn't have enough columns that are requested in the outer query. Please verify your code and add only one new expression per iteration if you are not sure where the **syntax** error is. It's easier than debugging a wall of code.